# camera2 api watermark on images

Tags: java, android, watermark, android-camera2

I am using **camera2 API** in my android app and i want to make some png watermark on images, please if its possible help me to make it thank you in advance. 
in other words, I want to make png watermark on captured photos is it possible?
in my opinion, camera2 API must have some method to make it but I havnt arrange of finding something on the internet there is not a lot of documentation, so i hope you know something about it.

```
 private void takePicture() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            return;
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try{
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if(characteristics != null)
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                        .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

            //Capture image with custom size
            int width = 1000;
            int height = 1000;
            /*
            if(jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0)
            {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            */
            final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width,height,ImageFormat.JPEG,1);
            List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
            outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            //Check orientation base on device
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".jpg");
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try{
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);

                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        {
                            if(image != null)
                                image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                    try{
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        outputStream.write(bytes);
                    }finally {
                        if(outputStream != null)
                            outputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            };

            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener,mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    createCameraPreview();
                }
            };

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    try{
                        cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(),captureListener,mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                }
            },mBackgroundHandler);


        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom image manipulation is unrelated to any Camera API, and therefore there are no methods to apply any type of watermark.

The solution is to load the photo as a bitmap, render the watermark through a canvas initialized with the bitmap, and save it again.

Some considerations you need to take into account:

- You will need to correctly manage the OutOfMemoryError if loading a
  large image. [Here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) some tips to avoid any problem.
- If saving again to JPEG, you may want to copy the original EXIF
  details to the new modified image.
- You should perform all this operation in a background thread to avoid blocking the UI, as the operation definitely will be time consuming.